# complex MP3 tagging app

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, id3

i'm a grade 12 java student and our last assignment is to create an app.
our teacher gave us the resources needed and i chose to create MP3 tagging software.
what the app does is simply show and change ID3 tags of MP3 files/other types as well
with a simple interface (using JavaFX). i don't want people to code my program for me,
i just want help with a starting place. i don't know where to properly start.
my main problem is where can i find all the right things for javaFX for example. how may
i find a method to create a drop-down menu. Or how does "choosing a directory" work because
if i choose a "directory" for my files what exactly does the program do with the "directory"?
thanks.

Comment: If this is your last assignment, shouldn't you already know the basics from previous assignments?

Comment: https://www.google.de/?q=javafx+documentation

Comment: As id3 library, perhaps http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/ is useful to you. Regarding JavaFX UI basics... well, I'm sure there are a ton of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

First start by learning JavaFX. Take a look at the book "Pro JavaFX 8". Its a great resource to learn JavaFX. The first six chapters will get you in good shape for developing JavaFX apps.

**how may i find a method to create a drop-down menu?**
You will find most of the  available controls in Chapters 5 and 6 of the book. Including a ComboxBox similar to a dropDown Menu.

For working with directories you will need to use the FileChooser in JavaFX. But till then learn the basics of the framework.